# Converting Integer String to Money Format

Tags: php

I have a set of integers that I would like to change to a US money format.

Here are some examples of what I would like to do.  The first number is what is in the database and the second is what I would like the money format to look like.

4500  = $45.00

395   = $3.95

19000 = $190.00

I'm really just unsure what function I should be using to make this sort of conversion.

Thank you for the help

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use [number_format()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

```
number_format((4500/100), 2);
```

There's also [money_format()](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), but it's slightly more complicated.

Comment: `money_format` is deprecated.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [money_format](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php), which formats a number as a currency string.

Comment: Ironically, money_format results are very hard to re-format.  Gives back strings like "USD 45.00" and weird things like that that are hard to simply add a dollar sign to.

Answer (score 2):

```
$number=4500;
$money='$'.round($number/100,2);
```

Comment: The question requires trailing zeros. This doe snot offer trailing zeros, or even guarantee a decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at [money_format()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.money-format.php)?  You'll just need to divide your values by 100 before using them w/this function.

Also, you could consider [number_format()](https://www.php.net/number_format) as well.