# Converting an int representing number of cents to money

Tags: t-sql, type-conversion

Like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335398/converting-integer-string-to-money-format), except T-SQL instead of php.

206275947 = 2062759.47

etc.

The problem I'm running into is that an attempt to SUM the values in this column is overflowing the integer datatype in SQL.

```
SUM(CONVERT(money,[PaymentInCentsAmt]))
```

Is just tacking on ".00" to the end of the value. What obvious thing am I missing?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

how about use money/100?

Answer (score 0):

If you are counting money and especially if youare getting overflows you should try making variables and columns as type decimal that allows as much significance as the calcualations need